# WP_User_Query from meta_key and orderby secondary meta_key

Tags: php, meta, wordpress

first of all i wana ty for existing, now to some real business, i need help with some code. I have this code, which works as intended, but now I want to order these by another `meta_key`. I've tried using `meta_query` to get another key into the mix, but am still unsuccessful.
I want to get all users where `meta_value => $region_id` in `meta_key => multi_broker_region`, then `orderby => meta_value_num` in `meta_key => broker_Order.`

any tips? would be appreciated

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'meta_key'   => 'multi_broker_region',
        'meta_value' => $region_id,
        'order'      => 'ASC',
    )
);
$aUsers = $user_query->get_results();
return $aUsers;
```

regard//

beginner

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $user_query= new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
        'meta_key' => 'multi_broker_region',
        'order'=>'ASC'
    )
);
```

Comment: I need to get users using one meta_key and then order the results by the meta_value of another meta_key.

Comment: Ok then [see this topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163696/query-by-one-meta-key-and-sort-by-another-possibly-null-value)

Comment: to complex to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `$meta_query` array in the query array to filter the results and use `$meta_key` with `$orderby` to sort the results.

For your situation, this would look like the following:

```php
$meta_query = array(
    'key'     => 'multi_broker_region',
    'value'   => $region_id,
    'compare' => '='
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        'meta_key'   => 'broker_Order',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'      => 'ASC'
    )
);
$aUsers = $user_query->get_results();
return $aUsers;
```

The link that Shashank Singh provided in the comments shows a more complex example of a `meta_query` which compares multiple keys with a logical `AND` relation. You can find more details about all of this in the Wordpress Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/. You may find the documentation to be sparse and little on the short side in explaining things—the user submitted examples may be useful to you.